# Pattern matching in nested lists

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't find the right combination of search keywords to find it. Apologies.

I want to do a `ReplaceAll` on a list of lists, for example, I would like:

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}} /. {i_, j_} -> {i, j, 0}
```

What I want is to turn this list into `{{a,b,0}, {c,d,0}}`, but I can't figure out a way to tell Mathematica to only look at lists that are one level "below". Running the above returns `{{a, b}, {c, d}, 0}`, as `i` matched `{a,b}` and `j` matched `{c,d}`.

How do I pattern match lists that nested?

Comment: Either use `Replace` with the correct level specification or narrow your pattern, perhaps by using the contents of the list: `{i_Integer, j_Integer}` or something like that if possible. I would post an answer, but I'm very positive this is a duplicate... Either way, hope that helped.

Comment: `Replace` is the way to go, but you could also map a `ReplaceAll` as in `#/.{_,_}:>...&/@list`. Use `:>` instead of `->` so that it works even when `i` and `j` have a value

Comment: You could also use `VectorQ[]`: `list /. v_?VectorQ -> PadRight[v, 1]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is to build a simple function and then map the function onto the list you want to change:

```
f[{a_, b_}] := {a, b, 0};
f /@ {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {1, 2}}
{{a, b, 0}, {c, d, 0}, {e, f, 0}, {1, 2, 0}}
```

Or you could use ReplaceRepeated:

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {1, 2}} //. {i_, j_} :> {i, j, 0}
{{a, b, 0}, {c, d, 0}, {e, f, 0}, {1, 2, 0}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for variety (more complex nesting may require modification):

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}} /. {i_?AtomQ, j_?AtomQ} -> {i, j, 0}
```

or

```
Insert[#, 0, -1] & /@ {{a, b}, {c, d}}
```

or

```
Append[#, 0] & /@ {{a, b}, {c, d}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without the use of rules i mention the following 2 solutions :

```
PadRight[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {2, 3}]

Transpose[Append[Transpose[{{a, b}, {c, d}}], {0, 0}]]
```

I often use such solutions to be able to compile my scripts.

Answer (score 1):

`Cases` works

```
lst = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
Cases[lst, {i_, j_} :> {i, j, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score -1):

Similarly,

```
lst = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {1, 2}}
Map[Append[#, 0] &, lst]

{{a, b, 0}, {c, d, 0}, {e, f, 0}, {1, 2, 0}}
```

Comment: This is ubpdqn's third solution. For variety, consider `PadRight[]`.